# Is the time-independent Hamiltonian manifold the minimum surface of revolution of the vibrating string?

Tags: differential-geometry, hamiltonian-formalism, string

If the Hamiltonian manifold for the moving surface of the standing wave is smooth then it must be minimum surface of revolution.

The frequency of the string is the capacity of the manifold that is a periodic solution to the Hamiltonian. The frequency cannot be a rational number frequency = velocity/wavelength because the solution to the Hamiltonian is a real given by the Dirac measure.

There is only one Hamiltonian so I think string tension and length are determinative. All I want is the mean curvature of the manifold. You are being asked here to prove the manifold is not symplectic. Obviously, you cannot.

I say you must conclude curvature is constant. You have no way out of this except to say I have not explained this to you well enough that the string makes coherent theory.

Do you have a calculus for the string as a moving surface?

Comment: Is it possible that curvature is not even defined on sine waves, so my question does not make sense? Isn’t this a problem in classical mechanics that is already solved?